# How to let dockerd create bind volume dirs with the correct permission

Tags: docker, wildfly

When I run a docker container with the following command :

```
docker run -ti -v /tmp/michael:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log jboss
```

dockerd creates the directory /tmp/michael with owner and group = root. This of course results in permission denied erros for jboss when trying to write its logfiles.

I have to create /tmp/michael manually and give `chmod g+w` permissions to fix that. dockerd then reuses the existing dir with the correct permissions. This is not what I want. Does anybody know how to force dockerd to create these Directories with the correct permissions

Addtional Information :

Dockerfile :

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
ADD entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT "/entrypoint.sh"
```

entrypoint.sh : (for testing purposes just a touch on the file instead of starting jboss)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
chown jboss:jboss /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log
myfile=lala.`date +"%s"`
touch /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log/${myfile}
```

But even here if /tmp/michael does not exist and does not have group +w I do receive permission denied. I have no Idea how to get rid of that

Comment: Do you need direct access to the files on your host, or just persistence of the files between instances of the container?

Comment: I need direct acces to these files from the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. `chown` somewhere in the ENTRYPOINT (making an .sh for entrypoint) (to make this possible from inside the container)

   Something like `chown jboss:jboss /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log`
2. Change permissions directly outside the container (in the host)

   You will not have `jboss` user or group, you need to do directly with de id. 
   Look the container `/etc/passwd` and get the jboss user id (`docker exec jboss cat /etc/passwd`), write down the id and make `chown`in the host:

   `chown 1001:1001 /tmp/michael`

Best way is 1, of course. You can use a docker volume for it, etc. Easiest way is 2.

Comment: My own personal preference is for option 1, have the entrypoint do this sort of initialization, because it makes the image more portable. +1

Comment: For testing I have a simple dockerfile `FROM jboss/wildfly  
ADD entrypoint.sh /  
ENTRYPOINT "/entrypoint.sh"`   entryfile.sh is `#!/usr/bin/env bash 
chown jboss:jboss /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log 
myfile=lala.\`date +"%s"\` 
touch /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log/${myfile}`   But even here if /tmp/michael does not exist and does not have group +w I do receive permission denied.

Comment: I was able to chown jboss:jboss in my CMD as my image is not based on jboss/wildfly. This approach is not possible for wildfly based images though. So I was lucky .... but in that case BMitch third approach could be an option

Comment: I've got an example repo out there with a bunch of steps to use an entrypoint to fix permissions. I'm making the container match the host rather than the other way around as you're doing. The issue you're seeing is that your entrypoint isn't running as root. https://github.com/bmitch3020/jenkins-docker

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Alfonso's answer, there's a third option to use a named volume to initialize the directory. You'll need to create the directory with the correct permissions inside your image first. E.g. your Dockerfile could contain the lines:

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log \
 && chmod 775 /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log
```

Then on your host you can create the named volume in advance:

```
docker volume create --driver local \
  --opt type=none \
  --opt device=/tmp/michael \
  --opt o=bind \
  jboss_logs
```

And finally run your container using that named volume:

```
docker run -ti -v jboss_logs:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log jboss
```

As long as `/tmp/michael` exists but is empty, it will be initialized with the contents of your image, including file and directory permissions, before the container is started.

Comment: problem is that /tmp/michael does not exist before the docker run command. I am currently trying that entrypoint thingi

Comment: Your proposal works very nice as long as /tmp/michael exist